# iPad SplitViewController - using an iPhone storyboard ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an iPhone app and now I am trying to create an iPad version of it. I have an iPhone storyboard and now an iPad storyboard. My iPhone has two `UIViewControllers` that have associated .m and .h files (`Pane1ViewController` and `Pane2ViewController`) that I built using storyboard, with storyboard IDs "pane1" and "pane2."

I have a `SplitViewController` in my iPad storyboard and I'd like to use "pane1" and "pane2" for the two views in the split view. How can I do this so that it inherits all the UI elements as well as uses the existing .m and .h files associated with those two view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom` to differentiate between iPad and iPhone

Then in your app delegate, create your split view controller with both view controllers: `self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[chapterNavigationController, pageNavigationController];`

Then make sure to set the rootViewController to your splitViewController: 
        `self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController`;

Comment: But how do I create the two controllers?

Comment: You can reuse your iPhone Storyboard. '[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pane1"]'